# How can I access server-level IIS connection settings programatically from within a .NET class?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-7, connection-string

### Background

- We are using a reporting tool which is .NET based.
- The reporting tool uses a settings file which is a pain to update between environments (doesn't do transformations, etc.)
- The reporting tool allows us to write .NET plugins to be run at certain times so I can modify the settings file on the fly
- We have access to IIS and can add settings / connection strings at that level

### Goal

I'd like to:

- Simplify deployment by moving all connection strings & settings to the IIS server-level settings.

  - even our developers have IIS available locally so this won't be a problem for them.
- Use the .NET plugin that I'm writing to connect to the server the app resides on and pull the connection strings and settings files.

### Question

How can I access server-level IIS connection settings programatically from within a .NET class?

### Notes / Things to Consider

- This application does not use a web.config.

  - **EDIT:** While apparently the app doesn't use a web.config, one does exist when the app is deployed, so theoretically I could access it via the .NET plugin.
- These are actually technically 5 different web sites. I'll be implementing the plugin the same way for each web site
- The IIS servers are only used for this purpose, so I'd like the settings & configuration elements to be global across all of the web applications.

Comment: This is a good written question. +1 and following :)

Comment: why not implement an ajax request and get a list of connection strings from specified webserver?

Comment: @Tigran, making sure I understand your suggestion. Are you suggesting to deploy a small web service on each IIS server and have that service spit back certain values, and then use HttpClient from within .NET to do a request to those web services? That's probably doable, but since this dll will always reside on the server with the IIS instance in question, I was hoping to avoid all that.

Comment: Also, I just corrected my question -- apparently there is a web.config file that gets deployed with the app, but is not used. However, perhaps I could use configuration delegation and then just access them from .NET like a normal web.config?

Comment: web.config files are cascade IIRC, so that means you should be able to set one at your default site level, and any sub applications should pick up the settings from the default one.  Here we go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use Memory Cache, MemoryCache class has been changed to make it usable by .NET Framework applications that are not ASP.NET applications.